# android show local html while no connection and if connection than load web url

Tags: java, android

we have a regular webview loading a remote url. "while" there is no internet connection we want lo load a local html file, and every 3 sec. we have to check if there is a connection again. and in case of true we should load the remote url.

we have already a class that checks the connection and gives us a boolean back

is there a way to check this with a do while?

our code looks like this:

```
    // creating connection detector class instance
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();


    // Check if connected to internet (true or false)
    if (isInternetPresent) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxx.xxxx.xx.xx/xxxxx/#/?h=" + xxx + "&location=" + locationName);

    }
    else {
    // if no connection
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/check.html");

    // HERE WE HAVE TO CHECK EVERY 3 SEC. IF THERE IS CONNECTION AGAIN AND LOAD TEHE REMOTE URL
    // PERHAPS A WAY TO START THE CODE AGAIN FROM LINE ABOVE isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    }

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you register a `BroadcastReveiver` that listens for connection change?

```
public class NetworkStateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(YourWebViewActivity.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED));
        }
    }
}
```

and register it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <receiver android:name=".NetworkStateChangedReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

And modify your activity to include this logic:

```
public static final String NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED = "yourpackagename.action.networkStateChanged";

private WebView mWebView;

private LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcastManager;
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED)) {
      // Here is your logic for loading the real page.
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxx.xxxx.xx.xx/xxxxx/#/?h=" + xxx + "&location=" + locationName);
    }
  }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_webview_id);
  mBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction(NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED);
  mBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  mBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

This way you will avoid the polling mechanism for checking the network state.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi Kiril thank you for your answer.....but i have no idea how to do that. i am very new to android. could you give me an example with my code? that would help me. thank you again

Comment: I had placed a comment where you are supposed to add your logic for loading your page. Now I have updated my answer again and pasted the code (taken from your question) that loads the real page.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, may I ask you to accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: of course i accept it. thx a lot. i have another question posted...perhabs you can help again. it would be nice. [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632454/android-use-webview-history-back-button-to-exit-app)

Comment: By accepting it I mean clicking the green check next to the votes of the answer. This way I will receive 15 points to my rating :)

Comment: ah...ok...as i said before i am new here and to android.